# need to apply no wrap and disable right carousel control in Angularjs ui carousel

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

please find my plunker for AngularJs UI bootstrap carousel [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/husdVRtelASNTKQumrIm?p=preview).

```
<carousel interval="myInterval">
      <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
        <div class="" style="width:600px;margin:auto;">
        <div > 
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" width="200px" style="float:left;">
         <br> {{$index}}
        </div>
        <div >
        <img ng-src="{{slides[getSecondIndex($index+1)].image}}" width="200px" style="float:left;" >
        </div>
         <div >
        <img ng-src="{{slides[getSecondIndex($index+2)].image}}" width="200px" style="float:left;" >
        </div>
        </div>
      </slide>
    </carousel>
```

In my above html when the first element index is equal to 2, I want right carousel control to be disabled, i.e. no wrap feature has to be applied.

i.e., In the following location, when the index becomes 2, I want no wrap and right carousel control disable to happen. Can any help me how to do it?

```
<div >
 <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" width="200px" style="float:left;"> <br> {{$index}}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution : I came this so far, at this point  I need to disable carousel right control. How can I do it?

```
$scope.$watch('slides[2].active', function (active) {
                if (active) {
       //Here I need to disable carousel right control and noWrap needs to be applied. 

                   }
             });
```